# In Jira, how can I make the fix-version mandatory when an item is resolved/fixed

Tags: jira

If an item is Resolved with a resolution of Fixed I would like to make the Fix Version(s) field mandatory.

Can I do this with Jira out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is the [script runner plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6820?versionId=41760)
You can add the validator as an embedded script.

Check out following link detailing out exactly what you want to achieve
[Require Fix Version if resolution is Fixed](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/GRV/Validators)

Answer (score 1):

There has been [a post on Atlassian forum which contained the same question](http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257302106).

Actually the main answer there was to use [Jira Suite Utilities plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JSUTIL/Jira+Suite+Utilities) and to add "a validator on the Resolve Issue workflow transition".

I don't know any way to do this in plain Jira (without plugins and custom configuration).